# Use the output of a thread outside of the threads function. (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm running a function in a thread, in that function im storing something in a variable. How can I use that variable outside of the function and after the thread finished running?
Example of what I'm trying to do:

```py
def f():
  response = 1+1 
threading.Thread(target=f).start()
print(response)
```

Comment: Exactly like you would with any ordinary function.  Threading doesn't change this.  You store it in a global, or add it to some global object, or pass an object into the thread function and have it update it..  The only change with threading is that the global won't be updated until the thread is done and you `.join` with it.

Comment: A global variable wont work. Im making a discord bot, so there will likely be multiple people storing info in the global variable. So the user might get someone elses output @TimRoberts

Comment: Take a look at `concurrent.futures`!

Comment: You can have a global list, and assign each thread an ID number that is it's slot in the list.  Another way is to use a `Queue`.  Have the threads feed their output into a queue, and pop the results as they finish.   The `concurrent.futures` concept is another very good method.